# overwrite file in Zipping

Tags: c#, zip

I try to Zip some .pdf files in C#. My code works fine but when the size of one of the pdfs is big, it is going to overwrite that pdf on the rest of pdfs. I am not sure what is happening. I tried to increase the size of buffer or zip file but still same issue. Do you have any suggestion?

This is my code:

```
    public void ProcessZipRequest(string strQueueID, string strBatchID, string strFtpPath)
    {

        int intReportCnt = 0;

        string strZipFileName = "Order-" + strBatchID + "-" + strQueueID + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm") + ".zip";
        strZipFileName = SafeFileName(strZipFileName);

        //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream ms = new FileStream(@"c:\surf\nikoo.zip", FileMode.Create);
        ZipOutputStream oZipStream = new ZipOutputStream(ms); // create zip stream

        oZipStream.SetLevel(9); // maximum compression

        intReportCnt += 1;

        string strRptFilename=string.Empty;
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        if (strQueueID != null)
        {



            String[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\uploaded");

            // setting Report name to path given for Report name

            foreach (String filename in filenames)
            {
                strRptFilename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);



                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\uploaded\" + strRptFilename);
                int bufferSize = 2048;
                int readCount;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                readCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount>0)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }
                fs.Close();
                outputStream.Position = 0;


                ZipFile(ref outputStream, strRptFilename, ref oZipStream);

            }

        }

        outputStream.Close();
        oZipStream.Finish();
        oZipStream.Flush();

        oZipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;  //  False stops the Close also Closing the underlying stream.
        oZipStream.Close();                // Must finish the ZipOutputStream before using outputMemStream.

        ms.Close();

    }
```

And this is Zipfile Method:

```
   public void ZipFile(ref MemoryStream msFile, string strFilename, ref ZipOutputStream oZipStream)
    {
        ZipEntry oZipEntry = new ZipEntry(strFilename);
        oZipEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        oZipEntry.Size = msFile.Length;

        oZipStream.PutNextEntry(oZipEntry);

        StreamUtils.Copy(msFile, oZipStream, new byte[4096]);


        oZipStream.CloseEntry();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `ref` for your parameter? It's clear that you don't understand what it means, and in this case it **should** be omitted. Read carefully: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: I get same result when I am not using ref.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue. I have to create a new MemoyStream in for loop and close it at the end of the loop.

```
foreach (String filename in filenames)
            {
                strRptFilename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

                outputStream = new MemoryStream();

                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\uploaded\" + strRptFilename);

                int bufferSize = 2048;
                int readCount;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                readCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount>0)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }
                fs.Close();
                outputStream.Position = 0;


                ZipFile(ref outputStream, strRptFilename, ref oZipStream);
                fs.Close();
                outputStream.Close();

            }
```